# Django: Accessing Logged in User when specifying Generic View in urlpatterns

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have a model that looks like this:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

    class Application(models.Model):

        STATUS_CHOICES = (
        (u'IP',u'In Progress'),
        (u'C',u'Completed'))

        status = models.CharField(max_length=2 ,choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default='IP')
        title = models.CharField(max_length = 512)
        description = models.CharField(max_length = 5120)
        principle_investigator = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='pi')
```

And I want to use a generic ListView that lists the applications for the currently logged in user, that have the status of 'IP'

I started writting my urlpattern and realised that I would need to reference the currently logged in user in my queryset property....is this possible or will I need to bite the bullet and write a standard custom view that handles the model query?

Here is how far I got for illustration:

```
url(r'^application/pending/$', ListView.as_view(
      queryset=Application.objects.filter(status='IP'))),
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't filter on the user in your `urls.py`, because you don't know the user when the urls are loaded.

Instead, subclass `ListView` and override the `get_queryset` method to filter on the logged in user.

```
class PendingApplicationView(ListView):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Application.objects.filter(status='IP', principle_investigator=self.request.user)

# url pattern
url(r'^application/pending/$', PendingApplicationView.as_view()),
```

Comment: Awesome, that's a great, simple solution! Cheers!