# Overriding Django profiles' profile_detail view

Tags: django, django-profiles

I installed django profiles/registration and everything seems to be fine. When a user registers their profile is created also. Now what i want to do is query another Model which is Company based on the user id of User. I dont want to change django-profiles view but add the extra field on urls to match and query Company model. When i hardcode the url (ex:put the id number of the userprofile like so userprofile=1, it works.). So when a user is logged in and goes to profile detail page Company assigned to them is queried based on their user.id.

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    #email = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    # Other fields here
    #company = models.ForeignKey(Company,blank=True,null=True)    
    #office = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)    
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.username




class Company(models.Model):
    userprofile = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, null=True, blank=True)
    comp_name = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True,null=True)
    comp_address = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True, null=True)
    comp_email = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True, null=True)
    comp_zip = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    comp_phone = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    comp_city = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True, null=True)
    #comp_state = models.USStateField(blank=True, null=True
    comp_state = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=2)
    compwebsite = models.URLField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    twitterurl = models.URLField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    facebookurl = models.URLField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.comp_name



url(r'^profiles/(?P<username>\w+)/$', 'profiles.views.profile_detail', {'extra_context':{'queryset':Company.objects.filter(userprofile=request.user.id)}},),
```

Comment: See here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9279753/django-accessing-logged-in-user-when-specifying-generic-view-in-urlpatterns)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to call it from inside a view

```
from *** import profile_detail

def my_view(request, username):
    extra_context = {}
    return profile_detail(request, queryset=Company.objects.filter(userprofile=request.user.id),
                       template_name="my_template.html",
                       paginate_by=20,
                       extra_context=extra_context)
```

Comment: The reason i didn't call it inside the view is because it is a third party app => 'Django profiles". Turns out my problem is easily solvable by calling user.userprofile.company_set.all .

Comment: You can do that in the urlconf itself?

Comment: No not in urls, within template.

Comment: Aah yes, that works too. Wasn't too sure it related to your question.